# How many questions in 70-488 exam?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, exams

How many questions in (Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Core Solutions)70-488 exam?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i remember exactly this year in the SharePoint conference i appears in this exam, I believe around 50 question and 3 /4 case studies.

I dont know if they change it or not. It is Microsoft property so they can change it any time.

Comment: Yup, around 50 questions when I passed it last fall